# ios - fading UI in and out instead of pushing new view - Bad practice?

Tags: iphone, ios

In some part of my app, I would like to fade out a couple text fields and a button and fade in some other UI elements with animateWithDuration.  I would like to do this instead of pushing to another view that has these other UI Elements but is this bad practice?  Should I be using a custom segue instead?

Comment: Are you asking from the programming perspective or the UI/UX perspective? At least for the former, I can tell you that it's a bad idea to keep two sets of (overlapping) controls in one view. Just use two separate views and adapt your animation code to transition between them using the same fading effect you're already using.

Comment: I was asking from a programming perspective. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It depends.

Generally, you should have separate *functions* of your app in different view controllers - that's what VC's are for.

If you are fading in and out different options/fields/buttons about the *same function*, then what you are doing is fine.

If you are fading in and out separate *functions* of your app, like payment and receipt-generation in a POS app, then you should use different view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried transitioning from your textfields and buttons? Since those controls are also `UIView`s you could try using `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html